# Is it possible to include facebook comments from a particular post on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

Facebook provides a plugin to allow you to attach comments to a web page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

but those comments are attached to the page you add the plugin to.

There's also a way to embed a post:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

But this doesn't expose the comments.

I would like a way to expose comments from a particular Facebook post on my page (like 'embed post' does for the post). Ideally, I should be able to place a comment on either the post or my page, and both would update to reflect the new comment.

Is this possible to do easily? Is it possible to do with the graph API, but complex (maybe by completely recreating Facebook comment behaviour)? Or does Facebook make this behaviour impossible?

Comment: Facebook has a feature called _Comment Mirroring_ in beta, for exactly that purpose. (You can apply to participate in the test phase; but don’t get your hopes up to high.)

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: While I wait for that, does anyone know if it would be possible to recreate similar functionality using the Graph API?